# iOS - Interface design resources

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm building an iOS app and I have all the functionality going already so it's time to sit down and make it beautiful. I'm not very savvy in this area, this is the first app I've made and I'd like some good, up to date or recent, resources/tutorials on iOS interface design.

I already know how to change the UINavigationBar for instance. But I'd also like to customize my buttons, my tab bar, menu bar, bar button items, and so on. Any good resources for this?

To be more specific, I'm more interested on HOW to do the customization on these elements, not so much as to look for good ideas on how to make them loon, though those are appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for examples of look-and-feel, or examples of how to create the UI?

Comment: I also asked there but, SO has a much larger user base that might yield a better answer for me. It's not just design it's also how to code it up.

Comment: Look and feel, Brandon, how to change colors, backgrounds, etc, to make consistent UI.

Comment: For the first part, this is a good reference for getting a feel of what you want to do: http://mobile-patterns.com/

Comment: That's a really nice site, but I'm more interested in how to do those things, not just get ideas on how to make them look. Still, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are dozens of great UI designers around the internetz and a couple of them have great websites!

You can absolutely use them as reference and as inspiration. But you will need to do the work (coding + grafix) on your own.

Your question is a bit to wide ranged to answer it easily. (almost) Every UIKit control has different methods to manipulate its grafix/design. E.g. a UIButton is easy to customize by setting its button style to plain and set a custom Background Image, but that won't work for a UISlider.

Custom images are a popular method to implement a nice design as UI. It's pretty great to work with a good artist or do it yourself if you are experienced with design tools like photoshop and simply add the images of your design to your apps but never forget the weight of images.

Keep the file sizes in mind and don't let a simple app have more than a few mb. (Especially if you want to support retina devices)

In addition to that don't underestimate the power of core graphics. You can do a lot of fancy design stuff like nice gradients as backgrounds or shadow effects by code without the need of images.

Since iOS5 there is a protocol called UIAppearance. It helps a lot to implement custom UI designs but sadly it is not backwards compatible. Just take a look at my favorite tutorial site for iOS stuff about UI customization in iOS 5. [Ray Wenderlich - User Interface Customization in iOS 5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5)

And last but not least some common design websites for mobile UI:
[dribble](http://dribbble.com/tags/iphone)
[creattica](http://creattica.com/mobile/latest-designs/)
[tapfancy](http://tapfancy.com/)

Comment: Thank you, yinkou, I ammended my question because seems I wasn't expressive enough on what I want. I'm interested in how to do these things (draw,change images, etc). Though I very much appreciate the tips and references.

Comment: I've upped my answer for core graphics.
But you really should make a list of every control you want to change and how you want to change it. Since, as i already stated, almost every control has different ways to be customized.

Comment: I have a pretty clear list, just didn't want to ask one question per element, would feel like I'm being spammy but it seems my broadly scoped questions haven't been well received either.

Comment: Ahh, and before i forget it. Which iOS do you plan to support?
Since iOS 5 there is a simple way to customize some UI elements, but thats not backwards compatible.

Comment: Right now I'm thinking as of iOS 5 actually, and then worry about adding hooks for the previos versions, I already have the NavBar sorted out in that aspect.

Comment: I was thinking on doing images for the buttons and nav bar, use drawing for the table view background and cells (not sure if I can do image for the cell backgrounds, or if I should). As for the Tab Bar that's the one I'm most unsure of.

Comment: well that's make a lot of complicated things easier.
i've updated answer with the UIAppearance protocol and a tutorial site for it.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. By chance I was reading his tutorial on gradients for UITableView.